# Angular2 Webpack Starter not loading properly

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I used to use the Angular2 Webpack Starter repo and it worked great.  Now I have cloned the updated Webpack Starter repo (production ready Angular2) and when I run it on the dev server and go straight to the **root route** it works fine, but when I try to go straight to any other page on the site by entering it in the url all I get is this:

`<% if (webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags) { %> <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %> <% } %> Loading... <% if (webpackConfig.metadata.isDevServer && webpackConfig.metadata.HMR !== true) { %> <% } %>`

I can navigate to other pages as long as I enter the root route in the url first and navigate through links but cannot go straight to any other pages.  I am not sure what to do with this error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You wanna know what fixed this for _me_? I'm on Windows, and what fixed it for me was to use `D:/` instead of `d:/` in the terminal. Pretty rediculous. I forget where I found this solution. It was somewhere in a GitHub issue.

Comment: [Here's the issue](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/762)

Comment: I appreciate the responses, and I actually saw that issue before, but Im on a Mac and unfortunately that doesnt work for me

Comment: this problem went away from me after I upgraded from node version 6.3.1 --> 6.11.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution that `fmoessle` mentions in this issue fixed it for me: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/1056

He says:

"I changed

`"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1"`, `"webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.2"`,

to

`"webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1"`, `"webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.2"`,

now its working with:
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
or
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Angular-Cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
It will solve most of your headache when configure webpack or dependency.